# Wordpress custom page display posts not working

Tags: php, wordpress

So I display my posts on a custom page like this:

```
<?php query_posts('order=ASC&posts_per_page=10'); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Now the problem is with the next page links:

```
  <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
  <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
```

On the next page it will also show posts from the old pages, it repeats, what I'm doing wrong? or is this the right way to display posts on a custom page template?

Comment: Hey, i didn't quite understand the problem.. do you want the pagination to be between the posts in the same category?

Comment: I want the pagination at the end, but to follow my `query_posts` and grab the next posts that aren't displayed by my `query_posts`is clear now Sir? Thank you!

Comment: check this out, http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/, it may help you with your problem. just need a little customization to feet your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination won't work as it should, unless you use the 'paged' query var. Check this out in the Codex:
[Pagination for query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination)